# Passing lvaue to non const references in c++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I read in accelerated c++ that we should pass lvalue to non-const references. Why is that? As far as i know lvalue is the one which can be modified. Please tell me if it has another definition.

I checked it by writing a simple program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<double> ret()
{
    vector<double> d;
    return d;
}
void rec(vector<double> &g)
{
    cout<<"entered..."<<endl;
}
int main
{
    rec(ret());
}
```

And error is

> invalid initialization of non const reference from r value

What meaning do `rvalue` and `lvalue` have here? `d` is a local variable in `ret()` and it is passed by value so it does not have dangling issues.

What happens when `rec(ret())` is called and 
explain to me how `rec()` sends its  argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Answer (score 1):

You said,

> **as far as i know** lvalue is the one which cannot be modified.

That is not correct. Traditionally, *lvalue* stood for a value which can appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator, which means they must be modifiable.

That meaning is still valid today.

Perhaps you are confusing with *rvalue*, which stood for a value which can appear on the right hand side of assignment operator, which may or may not be modifiable.

That meaning is still valid today.

**EDIT**

Now that you changed your question to say:

> **as far as i know** lvalue is the one which can be modified.

The answer should be obvious to you. when the argument type of a function is a non-const reference, only *lvalue*s can be passed to such functions, not *rvalue*s.

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to the comment by @0x499602D2:

> For user-defined classes you can use the assignment operator on *rvalue*s as they are like member function calls: `A{} = A{};` would compile given an accessible copy/move-assignment operator. I think the term *lvalue* designates an object that will exist beyond the expression in which it is used, and *rvalue* meaning the opposite.

Comment: that' my writing mistake...my question is how can some same say a 'd 'is rvalue...

Comment: @virusai, Here's a link to another SO post addresses that question in some depth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues.

Comment: Rvalues can appear on the left hand side of an assignment.

Comment: @0x499602D2, please elaborate.

Comment: For user-defined classes you can use the assignment operator on rvalues as they are like member function calls: `A() = A()` would compile given an accessible copy/move-assignment operator. I think the term lvalue means an object that will exist beyond the expression in which it is used, and rvalue meaning the opposite.